# After installing heroku cli, i got this alert about a trojan Trojan:BAT/Killav.DJ!MSR

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

After installing heroku cli, windows defender gave me a trojan alert Trojan:BAT/Killav.DJ!MSR,
affected file was this:
amsi: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
it said it is removed or restored

after the alert i did a search with Malwarebytes but nothing came up, i was wondering if it was a false positive or is there anything to be worried about. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too. It's a false positive as far as I can see and it's nothing to worry about. Heroku is a trusted company.

Comment: you may want to do a bit of research for this kind of thing. Anecdotal evidence is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

I found this same trojan while trying to install a browser. It kept turning on the Focus assist feature so that you don't notice it being flagged. To remedy:

1. I made a quick back up of a couple of vital files to a separate drive. Ones that I really needed from `C:\`
2. As of the moment, Windows Defender failed to completely remove it from `C:\` which left me with the only other option of resetting my PC and reinstalling Windows.

Luckily, after reseting my PC, none of the antivirus programs picked it up and seemingly, I'm in the clear.